# In Vmware Workstation Guest, how to identify which network connection is hostonly and which is NAT?

Tags: networking, nat, vmware-workstation

I'm using Vmware Workstation for my lab environment. I added two network interface cards for a Guest OS. In the Guest Os (Win 2016 server), I can see there are two network connections. But how can I identify which connection is for the hostonly card and which is for the NAT card? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you are asking: how can I distinguish between two different external network interfaces/connections from within the guest OS ? (aside from IP address assigned)

**The simplest way:** adapter in VMware appear to the guest OS in the order they are defined in the VM settings. but it may not be the most reliable in windows environment.

**The proper way**
Well, for the guest OS, the only way is to rely on the MAC address of the virtual interface. The guest will see virtual network MAC address, but you can change it/assign it yourself in VMWARE settings.

if you go to your virtual machine settings, select the 1st network adapter (let's say it is the one set to host-only), click "advanced" button,  you can note or change the MAC address listed at the bottom of the dialog box.

you can do the same for the 2nd adapter. now you can use these MAC addresses to distinguish between the two adapters in the guest OS.

[image]